# What is the correct flag to force Apache to build modules with debugging symbols?

Tags: apache, gcc, cmake

I am attempting to debug `mod_proxy` in the [latest Apache release](http://mirrors.koehn.com/apache//httpd/httpd-2.4.25.tar.bz2).

I have tried the following two sequences of commands, and both build Apache's core with debug symbols, but the symbols for the modules are still missing.

#### Method 1

```
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/dist_debug --enable-maintainer-mode
make
make install
```

#### Method 2

```
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/dist_debug
make CFLAGS='-g'
make install
```

**What is the correct way to force the modules to be built with debugging symbols?**

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Apache's make command does not take `CFLAGS` correctly, so they must instead be passed at configure time.

```
CFLAGS='-g' ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/dist_debug
make
make install
```